# how to prohibit the access to a view or controller in grails

Tags: grails, spring-security

I have a controller like this

```
class MyController {

    def index() {    }
    def list(Integer max) {      }
    def create() {     }
}
```

I have different roles like "Admin","User"
 and I want that only "Admin" see the "create" View. knowing that i use Spring Security

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/) is very clear on how to approach this.  Using either Requestmap via the Database for locking down URLs or by using Annotations.

If you're using the Requestmap you simply need to lock down the URL for a specific set of roles.  If you wanted to lock down MyController where create view was only available to an admin, it would be

```
configAttribute: ROLE_ADMIN   url: /myController/create/**
```

If using Annotations it would be

```
class MyController {
    @Secured(['ROLE_ADMIN'])
    def create() { }
}
```

Read the very well written [documentation](http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/) for more information.